# MySQL server table creation - "invalid syntax"

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I'm trying to create my database for a website and there seems to be an error I cannot solve.
For some reason it's giving me an invalid syntax problem, but I have no idea why. I looked it up everwhere.

```
    mysql> SELECT WebsiteDB
-> CREATE Table `MasaTable`(
->  `Username` varchar(255),
->  `Password` varchar(255),
->  `Email` varchar(255)
-> );
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE Table `MasaTable`(
 `Username` varchar(255),
 `Password` varchar(255),
 `' at line 2
```

I have no idea why it's pointing at line two. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Well thats odd, I just tried out my code in SQL Fiddle and it seemed to work. What could be the problem? I'm doing this through the MySQL Server 5.7 Command line client...

Comment: I think in your command line you need `;` to end a query, otherwise your previous query is taken together with your actual query.`SELECT WebsiteDB` needed a `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh boy, was that a stupid mistake.

I was using `SELECT <database>` instead of `USE <database>`, and I wasn't closing it with a semicolon. Thank you Mihai!

This works just fine:

```
USE WebsiteDB;
CREATE Table MasaTable( Username varchar(255), Password varchar(255), Email varchar(255));
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove last comma and use backticks to quote identifiers:

```
CREATE TABLE `MasaTable`(
 `Username` varchar(255),
 `Password` varchar(255),
 `Email` varchar(255)
);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6cefb1/1/0)**</kbd>

Comment: Alright, I did that. Still doesn't work, same error

Answer (score 1):

PASSWORD is a reserved keyword in MySQL.

You better not use it as a column name. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

CREATE Table `MasaTable`(
`Username` varchar(255),
`Password` varchar(255),
`Email` varchar(255)
);

Comment: As I said to the other comment @burakKarasoy suggesting I use no backticks, it has nothing to do with that.

Comment: I have tried...This query is working

Comment: Which version of sql you are working

Comment: Use small case for sql field name and database name.

Comment: well I'm using MySQL 5.7, that's what is so odd. I highly doubt the small case matters. I will change it tho